# Best practices for programmatic start, unpause, and shutdown of Gazebo simulation

Tags: ubuntu-16.04

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Ubuntu 16.04
Gazebo 7.0
ROS Kinetic

**Objective:**
For both regression testing and experiments, I want to set up a framework that:

1. Launches Gazebo and loads the payload models/plugins, etc. w/ the simulation paused
2. Unpauses Gazebo once it has finished loading
3. Run my experiment
4. Closes gz_server & client
5. Repeat
6. Profit?!

Does anyone have advice/suggestions/templates for this type of use-pattern?

---

I was planning to start Gazebo via the gazebo_ros package using subprocess wtih roslaunch.

**My primary concern is 2)**. Does Gazebo broadcast some kind of signal once it's finished starting up completely?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/19812/best-practices-for-programmatic-start,-unpause,-and-shutdown-of-gazebo-simulation/) by [josephcoombe](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3879/josephcoombe/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 609 on 2018-06-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I did something like you mentioned in my work as research assistant in the university. Probably this will become open source in the next month. So I will describe how i did it and give you some hints.

I have 4 packages.

- first generate's yaml files with the description of the simulation (models, poses ,plugins, parameter, etc)
- second loads these files and starts all launchfiles, spawn objects, etc.
- an observer to determine if a test has ended and if it was successful
- a logger to collect datas like rosbag, test time, etc
- (5.) a small visualization library

I also used python and the subprocess-API this worked fine for me. More problematic is to kill all the programs/nodes that was running (specially action_server like move_base). So at the end of the test i just reset the simulation and only kill nodes that i really need to be kill. Also over time the memory usage of my system getting really high. Couldn't figure out why is that. But for this reason i restart the framework every 100 tests.

Hope that will help you. If you have more questions please ask me.

---

Originally posted by [wentz](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2629/wentz/) with karma: 350 on 2018-06-25

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [josephcoombe](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3879/josephcoombe/) on 2018-06-25**:
Thank you for the hints/tips! Very helpful. I'll be sure to ask as I run into more questions.

**Comment by [jc](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6174/jc/) on 2018-08-14**:
Can you provide more info on how you used python?

**Comment by [jesus](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/8475/jesus/) on 2019-03-07**:
Hi @wentz, Did your code get publish as open source?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I am also working on something similar to run repetitive experiments. Some things that helped my in addition to similar things in the last answer are the following:

- I have a [very simple ROS node](https://github.com/uuvsimulator/uuv_simulator/blob/master/uuv_assistants/scripts/unpause_simulation.py) that I always start with my simulation to unpause the simulation at every iteration to make sure all nodes have time to start.
- To end every iteration after a fixed max. simulation time, I start also [this node](https://github.com/uuvsimulator/uuv_simulator/blob/master/uuv_assistants/scripts/set_simulation_timer.py) with a timer using the simulation time with the `required="true"` option to kill all nodes in the launch file once the timeout is reached.
- I wrote a [`simulation runner` script](https://github.com/uuvsimulator/uuv_simulation_evaluation/blob/master/uuv_simulation_wrapper/src/uuv_simulation_runner/simulation_runner.py) that starts the [launch file with all my nodes, including Gazebo](https://github.com/uuvsimulator/uuv_simulation_evaluation/blob/master/uuv_evaluation_examples/uuv_smac_example/launch/start_smac_task.launch) and then makes sure to store log files and the ROS bag in a user-defined folder, being also possible to override some of the input arguments of the launch file using [this YAML configuration](https://github.com/uuvsimulator/uuv_simulation_evaluation/blob/master/uuv_evaluation_examples/uuv_smac_example/smac_config/task.yml) in order to allow an optimizer, for example, to change the parameters of the simulation run. This [simulation pool](https://github.com/uuvsimulator/uuv_simulation_evaluation/blob/master/uuv_smac_utils/src/uuv_smac_utils/simulation_pool.py) also orchestrates the different runs just in case you want to have multiple simulations running in parallel.

I have found out that the number of Gazebo instances running at the same time cannot be too high, otherwise they start having Seg Faults, showing some errors that are related to the rendering. I still haven't figured out why that happens.
If you pack your simulation in a Docker container, you might also control that by setting, for example, the number of CPUs used, that helped my simulations a little bit so I could run multiple instances on the same machine.

I would just advise you not to use Gazebo 9 right away because of [this issue](https://github.com/ros-simulation/gazebo_ros_pkgs/issues/751). The `gzserver` is not being finished correctly after the `gazebo_ros` node dies, so it starts building up a bunch of processes with each iterations. Starting `ROS_MASTER_URI` and `GAZEBO_MASTER_URI` with different ports every time like done here in the [`simulation wrapper` script](https://github.com/uuvsimulator/uuv_simulation_evaluation/blob/master/uuv_simulation_wrapper/src/uuv_simulation_runner/simulation_runner.py#L216) is really important, especially if you want to still keep working on other things and running simulations manually while your simulations run in the background.

---

Originally posted by [musamorena](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2712/musamorena/) with karma: 41 on 2018-07-20

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [josephcoombe](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3879/josephcoombe/) on 2018-07-23**:
Thanks this is helpful - especially links to example scripts!

**Comment by [musamorena](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2712/musamorena/) on 2018-07-24**:
No problem, feel free to try it out. I am still changing and tweaking the scripts, I had a hard time finding examples on how to do this when I started. You can post also in the [Issues page](https://github.com/uuvsimulator/uuv_simulation_evaluation/issues) if you have questions, feature requests or bugs to report.